# Building a python virtual environment in codespaces using a devcontainer

Tags: python, virtual, virtual-environment, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces

I'm working on a data science project for which I have a repo. I would like to create a python virtual environment in the codespace when it is initialized so that I can execute code in Jupyter notebooks (.ipynb). I am trying to do this by emulating this setup (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLvAHhJAVlI). In the repo I have a .devcontainer directory which contains a devcontainer.json and a Dockerfile. However, when I rebuild the codespace, there is no virtual environment to be found. How do I proceed?

Here is the contents of the Dockerfile

> ARG VARIANT="3.11"
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:${VARIANT}
>
> Define the path to the virtualenv to work with
> ARG VENV_PATH="/home/vscode/venv"
>
> COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
> RUN su vscode -c "python -m venv /home/vscode/venv" 
> su vscode -c "${VENV_PATH}/bin/pip --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt" 
> rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp

And here is the content of the devcontainer.json:

> {
> "name": "Python 3",
> "build": {
> "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
> "context": "..",
> "args": {
> "VARIANT": "3.11",
> Options
> "NODE_VERSION": "none"
> }
> },
>
> "customizations": {
> "vscode": {
> "settings": {
> "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/home/vscode/venv/bin/python"
> },
>
> ```
>       "extensions": [
>           "ms-python.python",
>           "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
>           "GitHub.copilot"
>       ]
>   }
> ```
>
> },
>
> Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
> // "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt",
>
> "remoteUser": "vscode",
> "features": {
> "azure-cli": "latest"
> }
> }

I tried various devcontainer setups using various python interpreter paths. I was expecting for the virtual environment to be initialized and accessed as soon as I opened the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Just install your virtual environments to your source code directory, whether you're using venv, poetry, hatch, etc, there should be a configuration option. Then when the dev container mounts your source code, it also mounts the virtual environments. I usually install dependencies in `postCreateCommand`, which will detect the cache/mount on rebuilds and skip installation.

Comment: thanks for this answer! how do you know `.venv` is automatically detected? is that documented somewhere, or a srtting? i believe you (i took your advice - removed my setting for `defaultInterpreterPath` and it magically worked) but just wondering if you have any more info that.